# Insert variable in bounding_box on Prawn rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, prawn

I would like insert variable in my bounding_box text.
When i generate my PDF, my text is blank.

My controller action "show" in Order :

```
def show
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf do
      pdf = ReportPdf.new(@order, view_context)
      send_data pdf.render, filename: 'report.pdf', type: 'application/pdf'
    end
  end
end
```

My report file (app/pdfs/report_pdf.rb)

```
class ReportPdf < Prawn::Document
require 'prawn/table'

  def initialize(order, view)
    super()
    @view = view
    @order = order
    image "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/pdf/header.jpg", width: 540, height: 60

    # The cursor for inserting content starts on the top left of the page. Here we move it down a little to create more space between the text and the image inserted above
    y_position = cursor - 50

    # The bounding_box takes the x and y coordinates for positioning its content and some options to style it
    bounding_box([0, y_position], :width => 270, :height => 300) do
        text "Lorem ipsum", size: 15, style: :bold
        text "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse interdum semper placerat. Aenean mattis fringilla risus ut fermentum. Fusce posuere dictum venenatis. Aliquam id tincidunt ante, eu pretium eros. Sed eget risus a nisl aliquet scelerisque sit amet id nisi. Praesent porta molestie ipsum, ac commodo erat hendrerit nec. Nullam interdum ipsum a quam euismod, at consequat libero bibendum. Nam at nulla fermentum, congue lectus ut, pulvinar nisl. Curabitur consectetur quis libero id laoreet. Fusce dictum metus et orci pretium, vel imperdiet est viverra. Morbi vitae libero in tortor mattis commodo. Ut sodales libero erat, at gravida enim rhoncus ut."
    end

    bounding_box([300, y_position], :width => 270, :height => 300) do
        text "#{@order.company_fact}", size: 15, style: :bold
        text "#{@order.civility_fact} #{@order.last_name_fact} #{@order.first_name_fact}"
        text "#{@order.address_fact} "
    end

    table product_rows do
        row(0).font_style = :bold
        self.header = true
        self.row_colors = ['DDDDDD', 'FFFFFF']
        self.column_widths = [40, 300, 200]
    end
  end

  def product_rows
    [['#', 'Pictogram code', 'Price']] +
        @order.pictograms.map do |p|
            [p.id, p.code, '/']
        end
  end  end
```

I create 2 bounding_box, one with sample text and one with text from variable. The first one works perfectly but with I include variable the text is blank.

I think that it's about the context, on google lot of people add pdf.text to include variable but in my case i'm in the initialize method not in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Since you pass the `@order` object as a parameter to the constructor of `ReportPdf` you should access it via the local parameter

```
    text "#{order.company_fact}", size: 15, style: :bold
    text "#{order.civility_fact} #{order.last_name_fact} #{order.first_name_fact}"
    text "#{order.address_fact}
```

and you should add the parameter `order` to method product rows

```
def product_rows(order)
    [['#', 'Pictogram code', 'Price']] +
    order.pictograms.map do |p|
        [p.id, p.code, '/']
    end
end
```

and invoke it like `table product_rows(order) do`

Comment: Also you should check in the controller code that the correct value is assigned to `@order` before creating the new instance of `PdfReport`